# Parse PHP SimpleXMLElement into valid HTML

Tags: php, html, recursion, simplexml

Hey guys I need your help with XML parsing. I have a similiar structure like this:

```
<content>
 <paragraph>
  <bold>FIRST</bold>
   Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.
 </paragraph>
 <paragraph>
  <bold>Second</bold>
   Lorem ipsum <italic>nulla vitae elit libero</italic>, duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit a pharetra augue.
 </paragraph>
</content>
```

I have to parse this structure above into valid HTML. So my Idea was to iterate over it and transform each tag to it HTML equivalent. The Problem here is that the structure can be nested and I have to cover those cases as well. Looks like I stuck here :-(

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: First convert xml to string then You can replace tag like "<paragraph>" to "<p>".

Comment: Look up "recursion" and "tree traversal" in an introductory programming course. Alternatively, have a look at  PHP's [XMLReader](http://php.net/XMLReader) class, which I believe does the recursive traversal for you, and lets you iterate over all the opening and closing tags.